# Anything wrong with this simple RadListView? Tapping produces error page

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I had asked a similar question but had to go away for a month and it has dropped off the radar.

I have a very basic RadListView that I am populating using the (loaded) listener in the RadListView.

```
<GridLayout orientation="vertical">
<RadListView [items]="reports" (loaded)="onListLoaded2($event)">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
        <StackLayout class="itemTemplateStackLayout" orientation="vertical">
                <StackLayout class="reportStackLayout" orientation="vertical">                           
                    <Label class="labelName blue_text bold_text list-group-item" [text]="item.report_name"></Label>                        
                    <GridLayout class="reportDetailsGridLayout" columns="*, *">
                        <Label row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="left" [class]="item.status_class" class="labelStatus"  [text]="item.status_text" textWrap="true"></Label>
                        <Label row="0" col="1" horizontalAlignment="right" class="labelValue green_text bold_text" [text]="item.report_value" textWrap="true"></Label>
                    </GridLayout>
                </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>         
</RadListView>
```

Here is the component code.

```
public onListLoaded2(args: ListViewEventData) {

    this._reports = new ObservableArray<Report>();

    this._reports.push(new Report(1, "Mileage Claims", 2, 332.45, "Submitted", "status_orange", "Travel expenses for October"));
    this._reports.push(new Report(0, "October Expenses", 2, 32.45, "Approved", "status_green", "Expense claims for October"));

    this.isLoading=false;        
}
public get reports(): ObservableArray<Report> {
    return this._reports;
}
```

This displays two reports as expected.

I want to be able to tap on one and get the detail page. However tapping anywhere produces an error page such as:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onItemClick failed

TypeError: listView._listViewAdapter.isGroupHeader is not a function
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myApp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.js, line: 539, column: 62

StackTrace: 
Frame: function:'onItemClick', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myApp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.js', line: 539, column: 63


at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101)....etc.
```

I did have an itemTap listener on the RadListView but got the same error page.

Any ideas? TIA

==========================
UPDATE

@ogrodowiczp - I tried that and it did not work. Maybe there is a wider issue? I created another test component with a simple RadListView and am getting the same error page when I tap on it. Maybe I have not got it set up properly? I have uninstalled and re-installed the plugin.

My app.module.ts looks like this:

```
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
...
...
imports: [
...
NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
...
],
...
```

and my package.json:

```
  {
"description": "NativeScript Application",
"license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
"readme": "NativeScript Application",
"repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
"nativescript": {
  "id": "org.nativescript.myApp",
  "tns-android": {
    "version": "4.1.3"
  }
},
"scripts": {
  "lint": "tslint \"app/**/*.ts\""
},
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.9",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.9",
  "nativescript-angular": "~6.0.0",
  "nativescript-camera": "^4.0.2",
  "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
  "nativescript-modal-datetimepicker": "^1.1.4",
  "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
  "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
  "nativescript-ui-listview": "^3.8.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
  "rxjs": "~6.1.0",
  "tns-core-modules": "^4.2.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/core": "~0.6.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.9",
  "@ngtools/webpack": "~6.0.3",
  "babel-traverse": "6.4.5",
  "babel-types": "6.4.5",
  "babylon": "6.4.5",
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "~0.1.19",
  "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.5.1",
  "css-loader": "~0.28.11",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.2",
  "lazy": "1.0.11",
  "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
  "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.7.3",
  "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.12.0",
  "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
  "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
  "resolve-url-loader": "~2.3.0",
  "sass-loader": "~7.0.1",
  "tslint": "~5.10.0",
  "typescript": "~2.7.2",
  "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~1.2.5",
  "webpack": "~4.6.0",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~2.13.0",
  "webpack-cli": "~2.1.3",
  "webpack-sources": "~1.1.0"
}
  }
```

Thanks.

==========================
UPDATE 2018-11-13 15:01

@Narendra Mongiya I have added this onItemTap simple function but I still get the error page when I tap the RadListView. No console.log and no alert are generated.

Template:

```
    <RadListView #optionsListView selectionBehavior="Press" (loaded)="onListLoaded()" [items]="reports" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
        <StackLayout class="itemTemplateStackLayout" orientation="vertical">
                <StackLayout class="reportStackLayout" orientation="vertical">                           
                    <Label class="labelName blue_text bold_text list-group-item" [text]="item.report_name"></Label>                        
                    <GridLayout class="reportDetailsGridLayout" columns="*, *">
                        <Label row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="left" [class]="item.status_class" class="labelStatus"  [text]="item.status_text" textWrap="true"></Label>
                        <Label row="0" col="1" horizontalAlignment="right" class="labelValue green_text bold_text" [text]="item.report_value" textWrap="true"></Label>
                    </GridLayout>
                </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>         
</RadListView>
```

onItemTap in component:

```
    public onItemTap(){
    console.log("onItemTap called");
    alert("ItemTap event");
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

========================== UPDATE 2018-11-15 17:31

Another simpler RadListView that displays a list of books:

Component:

```
public getBooks(args: ListViewEventData) {

    this._books = new ObservableArray<Book>();
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this._books.push(new Book("The Adventures of Tom Sawyer", "Mark Twain"));
    }
    this.isLoading=false;            
}    
public get books(): ObservableArray<Book> {
    return this._books;
}
```

And the template:

```
<RadListView [items]="books" (loaded)="getBooks($event)">
<ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
<StackLayout class="itemTemplateStackLayout" orientation="vertical">
        <StackLayout class="reportStackLayout" orientation="vertical">

            <Label class="labelName blue_text bold_text list-group-item" [text]="item.title"></Label>

            <GridLayout class="reportDetailsGridLayout" columns="*, *">
                <Label row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="left" [class]="item.author" class="labelStatus"  [text]="item.author" textWrap="true"></Label>

            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</ng-template>
```

Tapping on the list takes me to the same error screen:

```
    An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onItemClick failed

TypeError: listView._listViewAdapter.isGroupHeader is not a function
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myApp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.js, line: 539, column: 62

StackTrace: 
Frame: function:'onItemClick', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.myApp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.js', line: 539, column: 63


at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101)....etc.
```

I'm at wits end as to what it could be. Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: where is the code for tap on item?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I had removed it and the error page was still resulting from a tap. I have put in a simple onITemTap event handler - please see above update to my original post. Tapping anywhere on the RadListView still takes me to that error page. Any ideas what could be causing it? Thanks.

Comment: I have added another update with a simpler RadListView that still goes to that error screen when tapped on. There must be something simple wrong! TIA

Comment: try to upgrade your {NS}

Comment: I updated the entire {NS} environment and still got the error. I created a new app and transferred the files over except the node_modules folder and it is now working. Thank you for your assistance and patience Narendra!